Screenshot of the Week #125
This contest is over.
previous contest | next contest
Hello and welcome to the 125th edition of the Screenshot of the Week!
To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! Daemons's picture from zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom won with 15 upvotes!


To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
Stack Exchange’s Code of Conduct still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.
How long will the contest run?
We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2024-09-30, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.
After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2024-10-07, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

No Theme
There is no theme this week.
As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a question of its own.  Additionally, there is the hall of fame you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.

It's possible to find wonders even in the darkest pit, from hollow-knight


I love that game! Can't wait for Zoteboat to release...

It was one of the most beautiful areas when I arrived there

Space battles get a bit crazy in the late game of sins-of-a-solar-empire-ii


Rough waters ahead in sea-of-thieves!


Parrying the laser didn't work this time.
zelda-breath-of-the-wild

Diego, Deb, and the Ancient Mariner taking on some of the most fearsome fish of Farovia and Roperia, including the mad scientist Sir Sigfried von Shleepskin himself.

Polaroid #31: “3,000 Days: Epic Journey!”
fish-wrangler

Nighttime in trials-of-mana


How about you have a taste of your own medicine too?
elden-ring


You need to look at Daemons' submission to understand the meaning of the phrase.

Sigh... time for attempt number... what was it? Definitely something in the thousands... I love elden-ring so much...


Hey, that looks like me!
